# Pattern to manage sequence of GameEpisode1 -> GameEpisode2 -> GameEpisode3... in LibGDX Game

Tags: java, design-patterns, libgdx, 2d-games

I have a LibGDX Game.

The Game actually consists of many separate subgames (Episodes). Each Episode actually being a totally different game (usually a different world, actors/game objects, textures).

No I need to code the sequence of transitions (Episode1 -> when finished -> Episode2 -> Episode N).

Each Episode is actually a Screen (ScreenAdapter) class, and within Episode1 class I have a field with reference to Episode2 (I set this field with Episode2 instance when I create and setup Episode1 instance). Same with Episode2->Episode3, etc.

I feel that doing this "linked list" of Episodes like this is very fragile.

What is the best way to do it better?

Now I have to call setScreen(nextEpisodeScreenObjRef) from currentEpidodeScreen object in LibGDX.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say that this design is "fragile", but a simple design would be to have an Array/List of all the Episodes and each episode would also known its index.

Then a episode change would be `setScreen(episodes.get(index + 1))`

The episodes could be passed to every Episode or be a singleton. Side effect of this design is that you could possible move from any episode to any else.

*The next step would be to also have a nextIndex field in case of a non linear episode sequence or multiple nextIndexes base on how the user interacted with the Episode*